# how to copy values from keys and convert keys to index with one function in php

Tags: php

I have an associative array

```
array(size=2)
'barcode' => string  ''
'nameEng' => string  ''
```

I want to get the array as this with one function

```
array(size=2)
'0' => string  'barcode'
'1' => string  'nameEng'
```

is there any way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [array_keys](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-keys.php) for that:

```
$keys = array_keys($the_given_array);
```

---

See an example:

```
$arr = array('barcode' => '', 'nameEng' => '');
print_r(array_keys($arr));
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => barcode
    [1] => nameEng
)
```

See the code in action [here](https://eval.in/610140).

Answer (score 0):

You could user `array_keys`:

```
$a = ['barcode' => '', 'nameEng' => ''];
$b = array_keys($a);
var_dump($b); // Displays the excepted result
```

Documentation about `array_keys`: http://php.net/manual/fr/function.array-keys.php